# How to call a API in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. and start all the execution after the responce

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want call a API when app is launched first time, in  AppDelegate class `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and start all the execution after the response.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you've already tried.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to do a network call (e.g. to check for application version), wait for a response and then based on the response, start the application from the right view.

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    let startupVC = // Create a temporary view controller in Storyboard or XIB (can be the same as your launch view controller)
        self.window.rootViewController = starupVC
    self.window.makeKeyAndVisible()

    networkCallWithReponseBlock {
        let startingViewController = // your view controller from Storyboard, XIB or code
            self.window.rootViewController = startingViewController
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Actually after the response it will decide the first view controller. Only for the first lunch not from background

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean. This code will be executed only when application is first started. After the response networkCallWithReponseBlock you can decide which View Controller you want to show.